# Problem sorting a list of pointers

Tags: c++

i am trying to sort a list of pointers (in my case each pointer is of type Job)
my intention is to sort the jobs by their serial number

```
void Container::jobSort(list<Job*> &jobs) {
    sort(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(), jobSerialCompare);
 }

bool Container::jobSerialCompare(const Job *jobA,const Job *jobB) {

   return (jobA->getSn()<jobB->getSn());
 }
```

the error i'm getting is :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::_List_iterator<Job*>, std::_List_iterator<Job*>, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2852: note: candidates are: void std::sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<Job*>, _Compare = bool (Container::*)(const Job*, const Job*)]
make: *** [src/Container.o] Error 1
```

i managed to solve the error by changing the code as follows :

```
struct compare {
  bool operator()(const Job *jobA, const Job *jobB) {    return (jobA->getSn()<jobB->getSn());
 }
};

 void Container::jobSort(list<Job*> &jobs) {
    jobs.sort(compare());
 }
```

no compilation error now but i'm wondering what is wrong with my initial steps,
help is appreciated, 
cheers

EDIT -
Thanks a lot for all the help everyone !
all the different answers helped paint a clearer picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all. You are trying to sort a list with a sort() that expects a random access iterators. List supports only bidirectional iterators, so the stand-alone sort() doesn't work. That's why you must use a specific algorithms for lists: `list.sort();`

Also others spotted the non-static comparator issue, which is unrelated to the message you've got (but still must be fixed).

Answer (score 2):

in your first version the `Container::jobSerialCompare` is a member function so it has an implicit first parameter of `this`, and so it does not fit to what `std::sort()` expects. The way to solve this is either to define the function in the global scope, or to define a functor, i.e. a class with `operator()()`, as you did.

EDIT: ... or to use `mem_fun` as VinS suggests

Answer (score 2):

In the first case `Container::jobSerialCompare` is a member function. You should convert member function to function object with a `mem_fun` function in order to use it with `sort`. Try to write

```
#include <functional>
...
void Container::jobSort(list<Job*> &jobs) {
sort(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(), mem_fun(&Container::jobSerialCompare));
```

}