# sorting a list of pointers c++ - no matching function error

Tags: c++, eclipse, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of pointers by a specific parameter of its class, working on it for almost an hour. it gives me error:

```
/src/ClassifyById.cpp:26:25: error: no matching function for call to
‘std::list<Worker*>::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

while searching I've found this:
[Problem sorting a list of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359587/problem-sorting-a-list-of-pointers)

But this is not my case, and I don't understand why my code doesn't work. as far as I know, I can't use functor in this assignment.
here's my code:

```
#include "ClassifyById.h"
#include "Worker.h"
#include <algorithm>

void ClassifyById::classify(list<Worker*> toClassify) {

    toClassify.sort(compare);  //ERROR### 
 }

bool ClassifyById::compare(Worker* a, Worker* b){
    return (a->getId() < b->getId()); 
}
```

Why doesn't it compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `compare()` function is a non-`static` member function which requires three parameters: in addition to the entities you want to compare it also requires the object which is pointed to by `this`. The trivial fix is to make the member `static` or turn it into a non-member function entirely.

However, you are better off using a comparator object with an `inline` function call operator if your objective is to obtain good performance: the call through a function pointer can generally not be inlined while an `inline` function call operator is trivial to inline.

Comment: is there a way to make a method friend? 
because i tried an inner class , and I tried making "compare" method inline,  and it still doesn't compile

Comment: You mean, you get an error for not being allowed to access the member while a member of `ClassifyById` doesn't have this problem? You can delegate from the function call operator to a `static inliine` member of `ClassifyById` or make the class with the function call operator a `friend`. I think i is possible to make a member function of a class a `friend` but I'm generally not using `friend`s - they seem to be unnecessary with the designs I prefer.

Comment: it does work for me with the "static inine bool..".
maybe I will use a different class for this method..
thanks!!